# Saftey regulations of multiple 1mW lasers

Tags: safety, laser, regulations

AFAIK devices containing exposed 5mW lasers are illegal without a license, but those containing 1mW lasers are. But how about a device with ten 1mW lasers? Is it still a safe and legal device? The beams could potentially be non-parallel and focus at a single point.

Comment: This question is probably beyond the scope of this site, since it's not about circuits or engineering but about FDA regulations

Comment: "legality" requires you to state the legislation you're under. Europe, Japan and the US will have differing laws.

Answer (score 1):

> Laser products are classified on the basis of the highest level of
> laser radiation to which human access [1040.10(b)15)] is possible
> during operation only. Other laser radiation fields to which human
> access is necessary only during maintenance or service do not affect
> the classification but may affect the labeling and safety interlock
> requirements. Use-factor data, if available and adequately convincing,
> may be used in determining the level of laser emissions from a
> product.

Source: https://www.fda.gov/regulatory-information/search-fda-guidance-documents/compliance-guide-laser-products-fda-86-8260

With this in mind (more specifically the `highest level of laser radiation to which human access`) the FDA would probably class a 5x 1mW device in the 5mW class. Because 1mW x 5 focused on one point could potentially expose a human to 5mW it would be classified as 5mW. So not a good way to try to 'get around' the laser classifications. The best person to ask would be a saftey compliance engineer/consultant that has actually certified these devices.